# Checkboxs leading to a fetch call to produce data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

As a user when I submit this form
I want a fetch call for each checkbox that is checked
So that I can load information from the API depending on what the selections are.

Using Materialize framework and jquery or plain javascript is fine. Hard question to explain but on form submit I want to bring up information depending on checkbox ticked. Each checkbox should trigger a fetch call to the specific API which will then append data to the new page such as movies availbe on nexflix or amazon prime

```
<form id= 'selectionForm' action="#">
     <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Nexflix" id="Netflix" />
             <span>Netflix</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Prime" id="Prime"/>
             <span>Amazon Prime Video</span>
         </label>
      </p> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : this snippet fetch every checked element and send a request for each one.

```js
<script lang="js" >

    document.getElementById('fetch').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let checkedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.filled-in:checked');

        let outputContainer = document.getElementById('output');

        for (let e of checkedElements) {
            fetch('https://api.publicapis.org/entries').then((r) => r.json()).then( (d) => {
                let outputContent = document.createTextNode('The checked element is : '+e.id+'<br>'+d.entries[0].Description)
                outputContainer.appendChild(outputContent)
            })
        }


    })
</script>
```

```html
<form id= 'selectionForm' action="#">
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Nexflix" id="Netflix" />
            <span>Netflix</span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Prime" id="Prime"/>
            <span>Amazon Prime Video</span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="Fetch" id="fetch">
    <div id="output"></div>

</form>
```

This is what you are looking for ? This example get Data from an API and display a field bellow the first checkbox :

```js
<script lang="js" >

    document.getElementById('Netflix').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let outputText = '';
        let outputContainer = document.getElementById('output');

        fetch('https://api.publicapis.org/entries').then((r) => r.json()).then( (d) => {
            let outputContent = document.createTextNode(d.entries[0].Description)
            outputContainer.appendChild(outputContent)

        })

    })
</script>
```

```html
<form id= 'selectionForm' action="#">
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Nexflix" id="Netflix" />
            <span>Netflix</span>
        </label>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="Prime" id="Prime"/>
            <span>Amazon Prime Video</span>
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Edited the question with more information. Materialize framework

Comment: Very very close to what i would like, but would be awesome if under the netflix and amazon checkbox there was a submit button which would then call the fetch function depenging on which items are selected! Thank you very much for that answer though, helps a lot